# Make client proxy variable global

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio

I must declare client proxy inside every method on the page like:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    proxy.GetStuffListCompleted += showList;
    proxy.GetStuffListAsync("teacher");
```

Can I somehow declare the `proxy` once?

Comment: yes. declare it as a static variable

Comment: or declare it singleton as someone else states

Comment: Be careful with singleton/shared proxies.  If encounter a WCF fault you must recreate the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a singleton instance of your proxy using a static property that returns the one and only instance of your proxy instance.

```
public class MyProxySingleton
{

private static Service1Client  _proxy = null;

public static Service1Client Instance 
{ 
  get
  {
    if (_proxy == null)
    {
        _proxy = new Service1Client();
    }

    return _proxy;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You may aswell just create it as a static... there is no point mixing singleton and static.

Comment: The implementation is already using a static property. A singleton is just a design pattern using static methods/properties.

Comment: Whilst a good answer, be careful with singleton/shared proxies.  If encounter a WCF fault you must recreate the proxy.